# Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, bigdata

I have a dataset that includes video frames partially 1000 real videos and 1000 deep fake videos. each video after preprocessing phase converted to the 300 frames in other worlds I have a dataset with 300000 images with Real(0) label and 300000 images with Fake(1) label.
I want to train MesoNet with this data. I used costum DataGenerator class to handle train, validation, test data with 0.8,0.1,0.1 ratios but when I run the project show this message:

```
Filling up shuffle buffer (this may take a while):
```

What can I do to solve this problem?

You can see the DataGenerator class below.

```
class DataGenerator(keras.utils.Sequence):
'Generates data for Keras'
def __init__(self, df, labels, batch_size =32, img_size = (224,224),
             n_classes = 2, shuffle=True):
    'Initialization'
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.labels = labels
    self.df = df
    self.img_size = img_size
    self.n_classes = n_classes
    self.shuffle = shuffle
    self.batch_labels = []
    self.batch_names = []
    self.on_epoch_end()

def __len__(self):
    'Denotes the number of batches per epoch'
    return int(np.floor(len(self.df) / self.batch_size))

def __getitem__(self, index):
    
    batch_index = self.indexes[index * self.batch_size : (index + 1) * self.batch_size]
    frame_paths = self.df.iloc[batch_index]["framePath"].values
    frame_label = self.df.iloc[batch_index]["label"].values

    imgs = [cv2.imread(frame) for frame in frame_paths]
    imgs = [cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB) for img in imgs]
    imgs = [
             cv2.resize(img, self.img_size) for img in imgs if img.shape != self.img_size
             ]
    batch_imgs = np.asarray(imgs)
    labels = list(map(int, frame_label))
    y = np.array(labels)
    self.batch_labels.extend(labels)
    self.batch_names.extend([str(frame).split("\\")[-1] for frame in frame_paths])

    return (
        batch_imgs,y  
    )

def on_epoch_end(self):
    'Updates indexes after each epoch'
    self.indexes = np.arange(len(self.df))
    if self.shuffle == True:
        np.random.shuffle(self.indexes)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that this is not an error, but a log message: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/42b5da6659a75bfac77fa81e7242ddb5be1a576a/tensorflow/core/kernels/data/shuffle_dataset_op.cc#L138

It seems you may be choosing too large a dataset if it's taking too long: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/30646

You can address this by lowering your buffer size: https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/doc/EDOC1100164821/2610406b/what-do-i-do-if-training-times-out-due-to-too-many-dataset-shuffle-operations

Comment: Why is the training process not shown?